# Java: how can I put two String[] objects into one object and pass them to the next method?

Tags: java, testng

EDIT: I did a very heavy refactoring of the code and I fixed this issue. Fixed code is below the wrong code.

I have these two:

```
public String[] firstname = new String[2];
public String[] lastname = new String[2];
```

and I want to pass them to this method (which already accepts some data from elsewhere):

```
    @Parameters({ "driver", "wait", "firstname[]", "lastname[]" })
    @Test(dataProvider = "dataProvider")
public void oneUserTwoUser(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait, String[] firstname, String[] lastname) {

        //code
    }
```

and this is the data provider from another class:

```
public class AppData extends CSVReader { //was public abstrac class before
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public WebDriverWait wait;
    public String[] firstname = new String[2];
    public String[] lastname = new String[2];
    public String firstname1;
    public String firstname2;
    public String lastname1;
    public String lastname2;

    @DataProvider(name = "dataProvider")
    public Object[][] setUp(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array) throws Exception {

        driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(new FirefoxDriver(ffox, profile, dc))
                .register(eventListener);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);

        int randomUser1 = randomizer (1, 250);
        int randomUser2 = randomizer (1, 250);
        firstname1 = array.get(randomUser1).get(0);
        firstname2 = array.get(randomUser2).get(0);
        lastname1 = array.get(randomUser1).get(1);
        lastname2 = array.get(randomUser2).get(1);

        firstname[0] = firstname1.replace(" ", "");
        firstname[1] = firstname2.replace(" ", "");
        lastname[0] = lastname1.replace(" ", "");
        lastname[1] = lastname2.replace(" ", "");


    Object[][] setUp = new Object[1][4];
    setUp[0][0] = driver;
    setUp[0][1] = wait;
    setUp[0][2] = firstname;
    setUp[0][3] = lastname;
    return setUp;
    }
```

Can you tell me what Im doing wrong here? Im new to Java - 4 weeks.

Im getting this error:

```
SKIPPED: oneUserTwoUser
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

EDIT Here is the refactored code that works

```
    @Parameters({ "driver", "wait", "array" })
    @Test(dataProvider = "dataProvider")
    public void oneUserTwoUser(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array) throws Exception {
        String[] firstname = new String[2];
        String[] lastname = new String[2];
        String firstname1;
        String firstname2;
        String lastname1;
        String lastname2;
        //parametrize tests by reading the array passed from CSV reader class
                int randomUser1 = randomizer(1, 250);
                int randomUser2 = randomizer(1, 250);
                firstname1 = array.get(randomUser1).get(0);
                firstname2 = array.get(randomUser2).get(0);
                lastname1 = array.get(randomUser1).get(1);
                lastname2 = array.get(randomUser2).get(1);
                firstname[0] = firstname1.replace(" ", "");
                firstname[1] = firstname2.replace(" ", "");
                lastname[0] = lastname1.replace(" ", "");
                lastname[1] = lastname2.replace(" ", "");
                System.out.println(firstname[0]);
                System.out.println(lastname[0]);
                System.out.println(firstname[1]);
                System.out.println(lastname[1]);

}

public abstract class AppData extends Mailer {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static WebDriverWait wait;
    static AppTest3 instance;

    @DataProvider(name = "dataProvider")
    public Object[][] setUp() throws Exception {


        // change to false if testing on local machine, so selenium will pick up the correct firefox binary.
        Boolean testingOnServer1 = false; //
        File firefoxPath;
        if (testingOnServer1 == true) {
            firefoxPath = new File(System.getProperty("lmportal.deploy.firefox.path", "/opt/firefox/firefox")); // usr/bin/firefox - another firefox isntallation
        } else {
            firefoxPath = new File(System.getProperty("lmportal.deploy.firefox.path", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"));
            // "c:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")); //for testing at home
        }

        //prepare Firefox and run it on Xvfb
        long timeoutInSeconds = 30;
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setPreference("dom.max_chrome_script_run_time", "120");
        profile.setPreference("dom.max_script_run_time", "120");
        FirefoxBinary ffox = new FirefoxBinary(firefoxPath);
        ffox.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", ":21");
        DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
        WebDriverEventListener eventListener = new MyEventListener();
        driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(new FirefoxDriver(ffox, profile, dc)).register(eventListener);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        final String FILE_PATH = "C:\\250.csv";

            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(FILE_PATH));
            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
            String[] nextLine;
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // 5 is the number of sheets
                    list.add(nextLine[i]);
                }
                array.add(list);

            }
            instance = new AppTest3(); 
            instance.oneUserTwoUser(driver, wait, array);
            reader.close();


        Object[][] setUp = new Object[1][3];
        setUp[0][0] = driver;
        setUp[0][1] = wait;
        setUp[0][2] = array;
        return setUp;
}
```

Comment: How `WebDriver` and `WebDriverWait` accepts a string? The type is different, can you post the code when you call this method.

Comment: It doesnt accept a string yet, I want to find a way to make it accept these two string[] objects, but dont know how.

Comment: If you really want to accept those string arrays, you must change the parameters to `String[] driver, String[] wait`.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand the question. You want to know how to pass the two arrays to oneUserTwoUser? Can you not just pass them in as arguments?

Comment: *`public Object[][] setUp...`* Why you return `2D` array? And where do you want to call the method `oneUserTwoUser` ? Inside the `setUp` method ?

Comment: I dont call oneUserTwoUser anywhere, when I run the tests, testng.xml calls it and starts the selenium webdriver tests. And about the 2d array - I dont know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@DataProvider` is from TestNG, and yes it needs to be a 2D array (so a test can be run multiple times from different sets of data)

What you are doing wrong is your `@Parameters(...)` line.  The Parameters annotation and the DataProvider annotation are for the same purpose but they do it in different ways.

However, I am also confused at your setUp function...as a DataProvider function shouldn't accept parameters (except for `Method`).  Consider a different way of giving it that `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` such as the way explained in [this post](http://www.lysergicjava.com/?p=165).

Finally, you comment said that that class was public abstract...is your test in the same class as your `@DataProvider`?  If not, the class with the `@Test` must extend the class with the `@DataProvider`. (And I would recommmend making it abstract, but that's up to you)

Comment: I created the ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> inside the setUp method, so I got rid of the CSV reader class and I create the String[] objects inside the method that needs them, and I also made that class abstract again. Now its alright :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Selenium API, but based on your stacktrace you might want to try this if you're automatically injecting parameters and it's throwing that error.

```
    Objec[] data = new Object[4];
    data[0] = driver;
    data[1] = wait;
    data[2] = firstname;
    data[3] = lastname;
```

It would make no logical sense for it to be a multidimensional array because arrays themselves are objects in Java and an injection method for passing in parameters as an `Object` array would probably take that into account. Therefore the `firstname` and `lastname` arrays can just as easily be treated like any `Object` descendant in that one dimensional array.

Comment: after I implemented this I got the following error: SKIPPED: oneUserTwoUser
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Data Provider public java.lang.Object[] com.pragmaticqa.tests.AppData.setUp(java.util.ArrayList) throws java.lang.Exception must return either Object[][] or Iterator<Object>[], not class [Ljava.lang.Object;
 at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:137)
 at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:426)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1389)

Comment: I think TestNG wants it to be a 2d array?